# SQL-Outer Join?

Tags: sql, oracle

Heres my question....

- The 'USER' schema has 2 tables that store data:  `ABC_DAT` and `ABC_SAT`.  They are related by the column `ABC_DAT_ID`.
- The `ABC_DAT` (`source_up_id` and `sink_up_id`) table is also related to the USER.BID (up_id) table.
- Write a query that returns all data in the `ABC_DAT` table, plus the `IP_NAME` for the source_up_id and sink_up_id.

I think I will need an outer join. I'm somewhat new to SQL so I am trying to figure this one out. Maybe I'm completely off and don't even need an outer join.  Heres what I have so far:

```
select  * from USER.ABC_DAT p
outer join USER.BID l
on p.IP_NAME=l.IP_NAME
```

But now, I'm not sure where to go with it. Like I said this may be way off.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: It's either `left join` or `left outer join`

Answer (score 0):

you can use "left outer join" for this.

```
select  * from USER.ABC_DAT p
left outer join USER.BID l
on p.IP_NAME=l.IP_NAME
```

This query contains ABC_DAT table as left table. So it returns all values from ABC_DAT table with corresponding values from table BID.